# organizing multiple email accounts and one stop solution from gmail

Tags: email, gmail

Assume you are a web master of multiple website, for each of which there is a different web master email account that you have to every day login and respond, you also have multiple personal email accounts ( for facebook and junks etc, for work, and one for university and one gmaiul for rest)! 
my question is that, is there an easy way to host all of the emails in one gmail account so that when someone sends email to admin@website1.com it goes to directory website1.com in that gmail and same way  emails to website2.com end up in another directory and also similar solution for when using your especial gmail account to reply those email back, emails of website1.com appear to the recipient as website1.com. you know what i mean. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for these settings as far as i understood :[How To Combine All Your Email Addresses into One Gmail Inbox](http://www.howtogeek.com/106034/how-to-combine-all-your-email-addresses-into-one-gmail-inbox/)